# Managing complications for a publicly known identity

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

We have a player that wants to have their Identity known, meaning that their name and face is known (or will be known after the events of the Silver Storm) to the public. My question is twofold:

1) What Complications would compliment this choice in a public identity?

2) How do I implement these Complications without stealing the story from the rest of the players?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good time to talk to the player and find out what it is that they want to show up as Complications. Especially where it comes to matters of identity and privacy, it can get tricky to avoid actually disturbing someone or taking things too far. They may be expecting having to deal with crowds and be shocked if you have Dr. Destroyer kidnap their niece.

So, some possible complications, roughly in ascending order of severity:

1. **Crowds / Autographs / fan letters** - Especially once they character becomes a prominent hero, they will increasingly receive positive effects of fame, but ones that can get inconvenient whether it's people showing up at the house, people sending undesired correspondence, or simply greeting him on the street and asking for an autograph whether in a book or on parts of their body.
2. **Paparazzi / Tell-all Books** - Fans will want more information on your hero than they may initially be willing to say. You may get reporters camping around the house, looking for a candid shot or to dig up details of your hero's past down to embarrassing childhood photos. Worse, they may start making up details.
3. **Blackmail** - Even if the hero is above reproach, there's no guarantee that their relatives and loved ones are at that same level. If someone digs up that the hero's cousin has a drug problem, or that their little sister's husband died in a somewhat suspicious manner. These matters might be used as leverage, other for money or for favors.
4. **Stalkers** - People of a vaguely compatible orientation, knowing where to find them, may decide that the hero is supposed to be theirs. Since the hero's identity is public, that provides that much more leeway to track down the hero's residence and/or use the prior info/blackmail tactics to force them into a relationship.
5. **Attacks on loved ones** - Whether to try to force the hero into a particular action or just to cause pain, the villain may kidnap, torture, or kill people in the hero's life. This is definitely an area where you need to talk to your player before pulling that trigger. [Women in Refrigerators](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WomenInRefrigerators) often don't go over well these days.

As regards not letting the hero's Complications overtake the story, that's just a matter of management, in particular being willing to say "no" or even just "not yet" if the player is pushing for the Complication to come to the fore. This is, of course, assuming that the other players aren't willing to play along and be part of this story arc. Ultimately, I'd say maybe give it a story arc or two involving something like a family member getting kidnapped or a stalker, and give the other heroes roles they can use to help deal with the situation, and otherwise occasionally invoke a situational Complication like an autograph seeker getting too close during a fight, or a scandalous tabloid headline meaning the police don't take them seriously or are even hostile. And listen to your players, all of them, to find out how well it's sitting with them.

Comment: So, how do I write this down on their sheet?

Comment: Easiest way is simply something like "Public Identity - Your identity is known. People may be able to Gather Information on your private life and act on that information." The rest of the effects are just interpretation. They get a Hero Point when you feel they're appropriately challenged by what happens.

Comment: Alternately, you can write out specific scenarios under Public Identity to keep track of what your player is alright with.